# Is there a way for Android apk to download executable java module and run it?

Tags: java, android, module

I've got an app in Google Play, as well as on Amazon Appstore, Huawei Marketplace, Samsung Apps and one more e-shop in China.

It's a puzzle game. Regularly, I implement new types of puzzles. Each time, I then have to make them available to the users by creating new version of the app and publishing it to those 5 shops.

Implementation of a single puzzle consists of 2 Java classes, a binary file and a few pngs (icons).

I am thinking that maybe it would be possible to write my app in a way so that it could instead download such 'puzzle modules' from my server? The apk would then need to be able to download executable Java code from Internet and somehow 'adjoin' it as a module to itself. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

it is possibile, but it is also restricted in some stores, in Google Play for shure. (also possible on iOS, also restricted in App Store)

this is just very unsafe letting developers adding some executable code without store reviews and informing users, so policies are forbidding it

Comment: 'restricted' as in - an app which does this will not pass a review? Google Play has some automatic way of recognizing such apps?
And if it is possible, do you have any technical info as to how?

Comment: I've just remember some articles when this "possibility" was developed and some apps implemented it. Both "main" stores started banning those apps soon, as this is against their policies. So I suspect that they "invented" some checking mechanism running when app is uploaded to store (+ scanned all currently published then). Check out these libs for more technical info how this works: [Tinker](https://github.com/Tencent/tinker), [AndFix](https://github.com/alibaba/AndFix), [Amigo](https://github.com/eleme/Amigo). powodzenia

Comment: PS. even Tinkers readme says: _Due to Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement, we can't dynamic update our apk._

Comment: Ok, thanks! Actually the Java code in puzzle implementation is quite simple, just a few simple methods. It does not seem possible to completely replace them with only data, maybe it would be possible to come up with some scripting code which would then be interpreeted by my Java code in the main apk.